# вывод на печать выборочно атрибута класса в Python в кавычках

Tags: python

1. Создайте класс объектов Auto для подержанных машин со следующими характеристиками:
2. Марка.
3. Модель.
4. Год производства.
5. Пробег.
6. Цена.
7. Отечественное или зарубежное производство.
8. Создайте 5 объектов со следующими характеристиками:
   KiaSor: «Kia», «Sorrento», 2003, 223 000 км, 415 000 руб, производство: Россия
   HyunSol: «Hyundai», «Solaris», 2015, 41 000 км, 869 000 руб, производство: Корея
   VolkPas: «Volkswagen», «Passat», 2012, 127 000 км, 900 000 руб производство: Германия
   LadaPri: «Lada», «Priora», 2011, 139 000 км, 150 000 руб, производство: Россия
   UazPat: «UAZ», «Patriot», 2011, 150 000 км, 345 400 руб, производство: Россия

3а. Создайте метод класса makeModel, позволяющий распечатать список объектов, причем на печать должны быть выведены только марка и модель автомобиля:
Например, название объекта auto1: ‘Kia Sorrento‘

Тестирование на сайте проверки задания выдает ошибку:(получается что нужно в кавычках, а у меня выводит без кавычек. Ставлю "" не помогает)
test_auto (test.TestAutoClass) (0.0/8.0)
Kia Sorrento
Test Failed: None != 'Kia Sorrento'

```
class Auto:
def __init__(self, make, model, year, mileage, price, origin_ru):
    self.make= make
    self.model= model
    self.year= year
    self.mileage= mileage
    self.price= price
    self.orign_ru= origin_ru
def getMake(self):
    return self.make
def getModel(self):
    return self.model
def getYear(self):
    return self.year
def getMileage(self):
    return self.mileage
def getPrice(self):
    return self.price
def getOrign_ru(self):
    return self.origin_ru
def makeModel(self):
    print('{} {}'.format(self.make, self.model))
def getAttrValue(self, attr):
    return getattr(self, attr)
def __repr__(self):
    return f'{self.make}{self.model} - Price: RUR{self.price},Production Year: {self.year},Mileage: {self.mileage}'
```

KiaSor= Auto('Kia', 'Sorrento', 2003, 223000, 415000, 'Россия')

KiaSor.makeModel()

Comment: советую поискать форум по этому "сайту проверки задания". там иногда такие странные заскоки у автоматического проверяльщика бывают...

Comment: Возможно задание некорректно сформулировано, и под вывести имеют в виду вернуть такую строку(?). И у вас в конце полетел код, дважды repr повторяется

Comment: `Test Failed: None != 'Kia Sorrento'` - у вас `None` возвращается вообще-то

Comment: Подошло def makeModel(self):
           return "%s %s" %(self.make, self.model)